# Why Java type inference fails in constructor for Collection of int array e.g. PriorityQueue<int[]>?

Tags: java, generics, collections, type-inference

I'm seeing some errors when constructing a PriorityQueue of int array:

```
PriorityQueue<int[]> maxPQ = new PriorityQueue((a, b) -> (a[0] - b[0])); // errors
```

> Line 1: error: array required, but Object found
> PriorityQueue<int[]> maxPQ = new PriorityQueue((a, b) -> (a[0] - b[0]));
> Line 1: error: array required, but Object found
> PriorityQueue<int[]> maxPQ = new PriorityQueue((a, b) -> (a[0] - b[0]));

However the errors would go away after adding the diamond operator or the full type:

```
PriorityQueue<int[]> maxPQ = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> (a[0] - b[0])); // diamond operator works

PriorityQueue<int[]> maxPQ = new PriorityQueue<int[]>((a, b) -> (a[0] - b[0])); // this also works
```

Comment: Because you omitted the genertic type argument, so `a` and `b` were `Object`, not `int[]`. so subscripting them was illegal.

Comment: related: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2770321)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about arrays. It's about the concept of raw types. When you write `new PriorityQueue()`, then **that is a raw type**; inference does not kick in (See: Java Language Specification); that's what the diamond operator is for.

Once you're in raw mode, be aware that raw mode is infectious. It makes not just that type raw, but most of the things around it. In this case, including the from-the-outside-in resolution used to figure out what the types of a and b in `(a, b) ->` is supposed to be. Because you're now in raw made, you just get the lower bound, which is Object.

Solution: Never use 'raw' mode - that was meant for old code that predates java1.5 (when generics were introduced). The diamond operator is fine, here.

Comment: …and never use minus to implement a comparator. Minus can overflow. `Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a[0])` does the job reliably.